# macbook pro 15 can't shutdown on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS , still that screen

Tags: boot, dual-boot, shutdown, mac, macbook

In My Macbook Pro 15, Dual-Boot OS X and Ubuntu: on Ubuntu everything is ok and when I execute `shutdown -h now`, still this screen:

[image: image of splash screen]

efibootmgr info:

```
BootCurrent:0000
BootOrder:0000,0001,0081
Boot0000* ubuntu
Boot0001* rEFInd Boot Manager
Boot0080* Mac OS X
Boot0081* Mac OS X
Boot0082*
BootFFFF*
```

[image: [press the down arrow key]

Comment: I'm getting the same thing - new pro 15 retina. If you press the down arrow key the splash hides and you can see the shutdown process - there may be some clues in there.

Comment: @jowansebastian    Thank you for your reply , I add the screen image

Comment: Happens for me too.  What kernel version you running?